# How to create view using Prepared Statement in Java

Tags: mysql

I want to create view of table using Prepared Statement in Java.
Here is my code:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(" create view loanCoolerView as select   *  , 
case when approved_by_asm = 0 and approved_by_rsm = 0 THEN 'PENDING'
when approved_by_asm = 0 and approved_by_rsm = 1 THEN 'PENDING' 
when approved_by_asm = 1 and approved_by_rsm = 0 THEN 'PENDING'
 when approved_by_asm = 1 and approved_by_rsm = 1 THEN 'APPROVED'
else 'DECLINED' end cooler_status from loan_coooler");

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

It throws error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't return a resultset, it creates a view, so you can't use `executeQuery()`

You either need to use `executeUpdate()` or `execute()`.

See [here](https://www.javapedia.net/JDBC/1793) or [here](https://javaconceptoftheday.com/difference-between-executequery-executeupdate-execute-in-jdbc/)